# KeepAlive Socket Connection in Dart/Flutter on IOS

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart

I'm trying to make a Dart.io Socket Connection "Keep-alive"
or somehow find out when the connection to socket is lost
the problem is that if i connect to a socket and then turn off wife and disconnect internet nothing happens.

this is function i call
in android onDone is Called but on IOS nothing happens
i even tried someone solution with RawSocketOption

```
Future<bool> tryConnectSocket() async {
/*Some Ip and Port that  can be connect to */
  String ip = "192.168.9.101"; 
  int port = 35000;

  try {
    late RawSocketOption option ;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      option = RawSocketOption.fromBool(/* SOL_SOCKET */ 0x1, /* SO_KEEPALIVE */ 0x0009, true);
    } else {
      option = RawSocketOption.fromBool(/* SOL_SOCKET */ 0xffff, /* SO_KEEPALIVE */ 0x0008, true);
    }
    Socket s = await Socket.connect(ip, 35000, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10)).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10),
        onTimeout: () {
          log("ERROR ON SOCKET TIMEOUT");
          return Socket.connect(ip, port);
        }).catchError((e) {
      log("ERROR ON SOCKET $e");
      return Socket.connect(ip, port);
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      log("ERROR ON SOCKET $error");
      return Socket.connect(ip, port);
    });
    
    s.listen((msg) {}, cancelOnError: false, onError: (e) {
      log("ERROR ON SOCKET $e");
    }, onDone: () {
      log("Socket DONE");
    });
    log("DONE");
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    log("ERROR ON LISTENING TO SOCKET $e");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the onDone method

```
 onDone: () {
   print("socket was closed");
   //You can reconnect here if you wish to, maybe after a delay. 
  }
```

Comment: This option not work either unless you close socket by close() function 
and the main Problem is with IOS

Comment: It should still trigger the onDone. Or just a normal ping every 5 seconds should be okay. So you know that it's connected and reconnect if required

Comment: I know it should work because it works fine on android it seems that it's a bug or something, how should i ping and check connection?